# Adding Linked Lists to a BST if key is identical

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I have built a BST dict in C. Now I have to tweak it to make it more efficient by making a linked list of equal keys. The data for each key is a struct. I am rewriting the code but I am confused as to how I will implement it in C. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's kind of difficult to help you with your code if you don't post it. Please post your code so that we can examine it. Otherwise there's no way we can make any recommendations.